# How to save date as an object to MongoDB using Doctrine?

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

When I add new record, date saves as a String:

```
"created_at" : "0.67200000 1407770545"
```

My question is how to save date as an object? I'm expecting to see something like this:

```
"created_at" : ISODate("2013-09-22T07:41:44.451Z"),
```

My code:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Date
     * @MongoDB\Field(name="created_at")
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
    * @param MongoDB\Date $createdAt
    * @return self
    */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @return MongoDB\Date $createdAt
    */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }
}

$user= new User();
$user->setCreatedAt(new \MongoDate());

$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
$dm->persist($user);
$dm->flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine with `@MongoDB\Date` annotation only.

When second annotation `@MongoDB\Field(name="created_at")` is added it doesn't save date with correct type. The reason is that `@MongoDB\Field` annotation requires to specify data type.

The problem was fixed by changing annotations from:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Date
 * @MongoDB\Field(name="created_at")
 */
```

to:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(name="created_at", type="date")
 */
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense